Migrating from legacy Google FCM to HTTP v1 for push notifications
I am migrating from the legacy FCM cloud messaging API to the newer HTTP v1 for push notifications for my app.  However in the new cloud manager for Pub/Sub I don't see any of the previously registered topics that were all setup when the legacy FCM was active.
Do the topics and subscriptions created from legacy FCM automatically exist in or migrate to the HTTP v1 api?  Or do I have to recreate them all again?
If they exist, where can I find them?

What is "the new cloud manager for Pub/Sub"? That doesn't sound like anything that has to do with Firebase Cloud Messaging. Link please?

I found it the Pub/Sub when doing a search for how to test notifications using HTTP v1.  Apparently its a part of Google Cloud, not FCM.  Its all a bit confusing: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/

Cloud Pub/Sub is a completely separate product and its topics are in no way related to FCM. See my answer below for more.

Topics are auto-created when the first token subscribes to them, and (iirc) also when you first send a message to them. There is no different between topics in the legacy or the versioned API, they're literally the same.
Given your mention of "cloud manager for Pub/Sub", it sounds like you're looking for them in Google Cloud Pub/Sub. While that product also support subscription to topics, those topics have nothing to do with Firebase Cloud Messaging. These are separate products, each with their own set of topics.

Thanks.  I didn't even realize I was bouncing between console.cloud.google.com and console.firebase.google.com - they look identical.  Is there any way in FCM to view and manage the topics?  I have never found a way.

Topics are auto-created when a first token subscribes to them, and you can send to any topic (regardless if there are any subscribers) (iirc). Nothing has changed on that front with the removal of the legacy API though, so this is all as it's always been. I recommend checking: the docs on managing topics, and Is there any way in FCM to view and manage the topics?.

yeah, so no new way to manage topics/subscriptions or users from the FCM console...has to all be done server side just as it was with Legacy FCM.

Interesting:  in the console.firebase.google.com cloud Messaging -> Compose Notification, the hover ? next to "Message Topic" says: Pub/sub mechanism for sending notifications to subscribers. Learn more ...   - 2nd time today I am running into Pub/Sub.

Pub/Sub is a common term for this type of system: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+pub%2F. Pub/Sub really just means that you use some sort of topic system to connect published and subscribers together. Google Cloud Pub/Sub is a specific implementation of such a system, but there are many, many others - like the one in FCM.
